# Debian ISO adding hardware driver

Tags: debian, iso, firmware

Primarily,

I'm stuck at configure network while installing debian. I guess it doesn't recognize my wifi card.
My wifi cart is Asus USB-N14, It has ralink chipset. I found something similar to this --> [Debian firmware Ralink](https://packages.debian.org/buster/firmware-ralink). And I don't know what to do.

What I need to do is to download the file in this link and copy it to the firmware part of the iso file?
Or do I need to do something else?
I would appreciate it if you could explain it in detail.

Also, I don't know if the link I gave is correct for my hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package you linked has this in the package description:

```
This is a dummy transitional package. It can be safely removed.
```

This means this package actually contains nothing but a dependency to pull in another package: [firmware-misc-nonfree](https://packages.debian.org/buster/firmware-misc-nonfree) in this case.

This is because previous releases of Debian had the Ralink firmware as a separate package, but the `buster` release has it merged into a single `firmware-misc-nonfree` package that contains multiple firmware files for several hardware devices.

Editing an ISO that has been specially hybridized to make it also bootable when written on USB media is kind of tricky, so Debian has an pre-made unofficial ISO available with the firmware packages already included: https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/current/amd64/iso-dvd/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I partially got the answer, but there are still some things on my mind. I found this on youtube --> [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1sbcUcQtACQ).  What I said above seems to be working. Since I am new to the linux universe, the point I can't understand is: will it work if i just download [firmware-misc-nonfree](https://packages.debian.org/buster/firmware-misc-nonfree) and copy it inside the firmware file? Sorry if i asked a stupid question. I just want to learn. @telcoM

Comment: It will probably work if you then burn the modified ISO to an appropriate optical media and boot from it. It may or may not work if the ISO is written to a USB stick, as the modification process will be unaware of the existence of the hard-disk-style partition table and bootloader added to the beginning of the ISO image, and might damage them. To make an ISO image bootable also when written to USB media, it needs to be specially prepared with [isohybrid](https://wiki.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php?title=Isohybrid) or equivalent process.

Comment: Okay, thanks for everything. @telcoM